# Java: return type of concrete method of abstract class becomes raw

Tags: java, generics, unchecked-cast

The following code gives two warnings when compiled with -Xlint. One of them states that type `C<Double>` is required but `C` was found, even though the return type is very clearly `C<Double>`.

I found a solution that gets rid of both warnings, but I don't understand (and want to know) why that was a warning in the first place and why it disappeared.

Code:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
        thing(b);
    }

    static void thing(A a) {
        C<Double> c = a.a();
    }
}

abstract class A<T> {
    C<Double> a() {
        return new C<Double>();
    }
}

class B extends A<String> {}

class C<T> {}
```

Warnings:

```
Test.java:7: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: A
    static void thing(A a) {
                      ^
  missing type arguments for generic class A<T>
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in class A
Test.java:8: warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
        C<Double> c = a.a();
                         ^
  required: C<Double>
  found:    C
2 warnings
```

Solution to the warnings:

I changed `static void thing(A a)` to `static void thing(A<?> a)`.

But:

There is no reason for `a.a()` to return `C` rather than `C<Double>` which is the return type stated everywhere. I don't see why `A` being raw should make the return type of all of its methods raw, when the type parameters of `A` don't affect `.a()`;

Comment: Rawtypes only still exist for backward compatibility. If generics had existed from the beginning of Java, `A` (without a type parameter) was never allowed. See also [why we shouldn't use raw types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it).

Comment: I think you are right - the reason why generics unrelated to the omitted type parameters need to get erased is unclear; but it is consistent with the behavior described in the language spec. Perhaps the spec could have been written more carefully to avoid this problem; or maybe it was a deliberate simplification, because you *really* shouldn't use raw types, so you shouldn't need to see this behavior in the first place.

Comment: which java version? i do not see those warnings in 1.8.